# Ascending sort, c++, with vectors

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector

I am trying to make a sort function for `std::vector`, but I have a problem with negative `values`. I don't want to use function `vector::sort`.
Queue is a vector.

**My input :**

```
1, -2, -241, 332, 2667, -2667, 266217, 2667, 13, -22, -41, 2332
```

**Output :**

```
266217, 2667, 2667, 2332, 332, 13, 1, -2. -241, -2667, -22, -41
```

Basically everything works, and then it crashes from unclear reasons for me.

**Function :**

```
void PriorityQueue::Push(double value)
{
    std::vector<double>::iterator pr;

    if (Queue.empty())
    {
        Queue.push_back(value);
    }

    else if (!Queue.empty())
    {
        for (pr = Queue.begin(); pr != Queue.end(); pr++)
        {
            if (value > *pr || value == *pr)
            {
                Queue.insert(pr, value);
                break;
            }

            else if (value < 0)
            {
                if (value > *pr || value == *pr)
                {
                    Queue.insert(pr, value);
                    break;
                }

                else if (value < *pr)
                {
                    Queue.push_back(value);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: I think it's easier if you push_back into vector first then implement and use a sorting algorithm like merge sort on the unsorted container. Also, why `value > *pr || value == *pr` and not `value >= *pr`?

Comment: Why do you say: `if (value > *pr || value == *pr)` instead of the more readable expression: `if (value >= *pr)`

Comment: What is the reason for not using `std::sort`?

Comment: While I don't understand your sorting algorithm with regards to negative numbers, there's nothing in your code that would cause a crash.  The crash is probably happening in code you haven't shown us yet.

Comment: If your input as ordered as `{5,4,3,2,1}` and you called `Push` for each value (in order), only `5` would get inserted into the queue. Do see why?

Comment: What is special about negative numbers in your priority queue which requires special treatment in your sorting algorithm.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::upper_bound`?

Comment: The initial "12" is mysterious (you're possibly doing something wrong when outputting), but otherwise it's as your code says: descending positives followed by the negatives in the order they were added.

Comment: Rewriting your conditional makes it clearer what's happening: `if (value >= *pr) { Queue.insert(pr, value); break; } else if (value < 0 && value < *pr) { Queue.push_back(value); break; }`. Note that if the first value is non-negative, all negatives are added at the end.

Comment: If I wont consider values < 0 separately, they are disappearing in the program..

Comment: @Xuuuc - the reason why negative numbers are "disappearing" is because you have a bug in your program. When `value` is less than the less element in the list, your code won't insert it.  See my answer below for a very simple solution.

Comment: The title to your question says "ascending sort". But what your desired output and code are attempting is really "descending sort".

Comment: Not using `vector::sort` will be easy, since there is no such thing.

Answer (score 1):

1. It really hard to understand desirable order in this method. But I will try. You use

   ```
   Queue.insert(pr, value);
   ```

so I assume that pr should be before value in case value>=*pr. That means descending order, from max to min.

2. You want descending order. Then you need position when previous was bigger or equals and current element is less then value. So skip all until this position found and then insert.

   ```
   void PriorityQueue::Push(double value) {
      std::vector<double>::iterator pr;
      if (Queue.empty()) {
          Queue.push_back(value);
          return;
      }
      for (pr = Queue.begin(); pr != Queue.end(); pr++) {
           if (value < *pr)
               continue;
           Queue.insert(pr,value);
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

And for ascending order - skip all until first that bigger and then insert:

```
    void PriorityQueue::Push(double value) {
       std::vector<double>::iterator pr;
       if (Queue.empty()) {
           Queue.push_back(value);
           return;
       }
       for (pr = Queue.begin(); pr != Queue.end(); pr++) {
            if (value >= *pr)
                continue;
            Queue.insert(pr,value);
            break;
        }
    }
```

3. You don't need to check "if (value<0)" - I think your logical mistake was made at this step. Also you don't need to check

   ```
   if (!Queue.empty())
   ```

   in else-statement after

   ```
   if (Queue.empty())
   ```

   this is too much checking and can cause many mistakes...

Comment: When I use this code, I am losing all negative values in the program. They are gone (it happened in my program before, that's why I used statement "if (values < 0)"

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain, based on the hints you've given in your comments, this is what you want.  It doesn't need to treat the empty list or negative numbers special.  And if `value` doesn't get inserted within the for loop, it's assumed to be at the end.

```
void PriorityQueue::Push(double value)
{
    bool inserted = false;

    for (auto pr = Queue.begin(); pr != Queue.end(); pr++)
    {
        if (value >= *pr)
        {
            Queue.insert(pr, value);
            inserted = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (inserted == false) // handle the case of inserting a number at the end
    {
        Queue.push_back(value);
    }
}
```

This will reliably insert elements in descending order without having any special need to treat negative numbers special.